# Create custom LazyColumn/LazyList to add custom items in between

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to create a custom `LazyColumn`/`LazyRow`to create a generic list that shows ads in different types: at the top, bottom or combined (each 3 items for instance).

I've just copied the implementation of `LazyColumn` and created my custom, adding some new parameters.

```
@Composable
fun CustomLazyColumnWithAds(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    state: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState(),
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(0.dp),
    reverseLayout: Boolean = false,
    verticalArrangement: Arrangement.Vertical =
        if (!reverseLayout) Arrangement.Top else Arrangement.Bottom,
    horizontalAlignment: Alignment.Horizontal = Alignment.Start,
    flingBehavior: FlingBehavior = ScrollableDefaults.flingBehavior(),
    userScrollEnabled: Boolean = true,
    adsPosition: AdsPosition,
    content: LazyListScope.() -> Unit
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier,
        state = state,
        contentPadding = contentPadding,
        reverseLayout = reverseLayout,
        verticalArrangement = verticalArrangement,
        horizontalAlignment = horizontalAlignment,
        flingBehavior = flingBehavior,
        userScrollEnabled = userScrollEnabled
    ) {
        when (adsPosition) {
            is AdsPosition.Top -> {
                item {
                    Ad()
                }
                content()
            }

            is AdsPosition.Combined -> {
                content()
            }

            is AdsPosition.Bottom -> {
                content()
                item {
                    Ad()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem doing this is that in case one list is using `stickyHeader` wouldn't work neither if I have one or more `Footer` for instance legal terms and an animation at the bottom of the list, so I'm looking for more ways of doing this, I need to do this because I need to implement to a bunch of lists of my app this and Ads are from my backend so I need to do an extra-call to get this ads before creating this list.

Any idea of how can I improve this?

Problems I've faced :
If I add items in between I lost the index, so if other features need a callback perhaps the index is wrong.
If feature have more than one header or footer I can not determine the order.

### TL;DR

I'd like to have a `LazyColumn`, `Column`, `LazyRow`, `Row`, whatever so other feature can configure it as : offerPosition = Position.TOP so the list is smart enough to add an `Offer` there, the problem is that I'd have to create a system to let the feature owner decide which one is the first position, because maybe the first position is something super important and it must be below of it, so that's why the idea I've made for the first iteration won't work because it's just the happy path.

Does it make sense to create this? Is there any other way to do this? I'm trying to add `Offers` in other features list and I want the less work for them.

Example of how should work this list :

[image]

The image represents the happy path, but the list may differ between features, so the important thing here is that this `CustomList` should let the user choose if they want a multiple footer or not, because there are features that have 2 footer (last items) and perhaps even if they put OfferPosition.BOTTOM they want it before the footer or just after.

Here is also important that I wouldn't like to touch/change a lot the implementaiton of the other features, so the way they introduce their items shouldn't change at all, because they order it and chose the position of each section. It's important that in the screen each section could be like different types of flights for instance and they want it to split between `LazyRow`.

Here the question is, what's better :

1. Create a custom list that ads the items as the same config of the user, if they want top it goes to top.
2. Create an Offer composable that they can get and choose where they want to add it.

Also I'm afraid of how will affect adding this "Offer" to the index of their list when tapping on an item that is not an Offer.

Comment: I'd like to help out, but you'll need to be a bit more specific. It sounds like simply adding an `item` before or after the content isn't good enough. So, what do you need? Can you specify how sticky headers need to behave? Can the list items be split? Do you need custom item keys or just indices? Et cetera. Perhaps a picture can help?

Comment: @Jorn just added more information + a photo clarification

Comment: The best way to create a custom list that can display ads in different positions is to use a Slot compose. please check this https://github.com/jshvarts/ComposeSlotApiDemo

Comment: thanks for answering, but this wouldn't work if I want the Combined one, right?

Comment: In this case it would be better to map against data with LazyVerticalGrid not a LazyColumn

Comment: You can wrap data inside some custom data class such as ListData(type, data, callback, gridSize) and based on that data you can set positions and callbacks as well. Wouldn't it be better approach?

Comment: The thing is that I'd need it on all types of list, Row, Grid, normal list (vertical with 1 item), etc..

Comment: The idea is to do something like this https://github.com/clockbyte/admobadapter or https://github.com/daoibrahim/AdmobAdvancedNativeRecyclerview but in compose and instead of ads my own composables.

Comment: This question is not just adding some item between  if you want to implement `The thing is that I'd need it on all types of list, Row, Grid, normal list (vertical with 1 item), etc.. – `. What you need to do is create a data structure that selects LazyColumn/Row/Grid and passes to suitable composable a data structure such as ListData(type, data, callback, gridSize) based on this type you need to select which composable to show this data in. or you can pass Composable inside data to be invoked either. But implementation of this is not just passing some items between

Comment: Feel free to propose an option knowing what is desire, modifying the less possible add an ad() on an existing list, from now at the top, but I'd like to modify it to be able to print it to top/bot/combined (each x items)

Comment: @Thracian hello can you help me out on this one? I'm sure you know what's missing on this one :( 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78198317/compose-align-column-max-height

Answer (score 2):

instead of encapsulating the entire LazyColumn, consider creating a utility function that modifies the LazyListScope content dynamically. This utility function can inject the ads into the content provided based on the desired position.

```
@Composable
fun LazyListScope.InjectAds(
    adsPosition: AdsPosition,
    content: LazyListScope.() -> Unit
) {
    when (adsPosition) {
        is AdsPosition.Top -> {
            item { Ad() }
            content()
        }
        is AdsPosition.Combined -> {
            var index = 0
            content().also {
                if (index % 3 == 0) {
                    item { Ad() }
                }
                index++
            }
        }
        is AdsPosition.Bottom -> {
            content()
            item { Ad() }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyLazyColumnWithAds(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    adsPosition: AdsPosition,
    content: LazyListScope.() -> Unit
) {
    LazyColumn(modifier = modifier) {
        InjectAds(adsPosition) {
            content()
        }
    }
}

MyLazyColumnWithAds(adsPosition = AdsPosition.Combined) {
    items(listOfItems) { item ->
        // Render each item
    }

    stickyHeader {
        // Header content
    }

    item {
        // Footer or other items
    }
}
```

update

maybe you can try the following
create an new item list

```
sealed class ItemHolder {
    data class Content(val data: YourDataModel) : ItemHolder()
    data class Ad(val adData: AdDataModel) : ItemHolder()
    data class Header(val headerData: HeaderDataModel) : ItemHolder()
    //... add more types if needed
}
```

in your lazy column check whether is a content, ad or header. order the list according to your needs

prepare your list

```
fun prepareListWithAds(
    originalList: List<YourDataModel>,
    adsPosition: AdsPosition
): List<ItemHolder> {
    val resultList = mutableListOf<ItemHolder>()
    when (adsPosition) {
        is AdsPosition.Top -> {
            resultList.add(ItemHolder.Ad(AdDataModel()))
            resultList.addAll(originalList.map { ItemHolder.Content(it) })
        }
        is AdsPosition.Bottom -> {
            resultList.addAll(originalList.map { ItemHolder.Content(it) })
            resultList.add(ItemHolder.Ad(AdDataModel()))
        }
        is AdsPosition.Combined -> {
            // Add your logic for combined ads
        }
    }
    return resultList
}
```

then use it

```
val itemsWithAds = prepareListWithAds(myOriginalList, AdsPosition.Top)

LazyColumn {
    items(itemsWithAds) { item ->
        when (item) {
            is ItemHolder.Content -> { /* Display content */ }
            is ItemHolder.Ad -> { Ad() }
            is ItemHolder.Header -> { /* Display header */ }
            // ... handle other cases
        }
    }
}
```

you can handle the click events for each type of the itemHolder

Comment: Thanks for replying but I guess in combined won't work, right? And what about if the list is a grid for instance you have sticky header and 4 items as grid  of 2, but then I want to add an add before this 2 items that occupies one, let's say horizontal?

Comment: just edited my question let me know if you can help me better now

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: May you add an example with the last one to check how would work?

Comment: check I home it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ad to be at a certain position in between the rest of your items, you could use something like this:

```
fun <T> LazyListScope.itemsWithAd(
    items: List<T>,
    adItem: @Composable LazyItemScope.() -> Unit,
    adPosition: Int = 0,
    itemContent: @Composable LazyItemScope.(T) -> Unit
) = items(items.size + 1) { index ->
    when {
        index < adPosition -> itemContent(items[index])
        index > adPosition -> itemContent(items[index + 1])
        else -> adItem()
    }
}
```

If you need a "break" in the list, you'll have to break up the `items`:

```
fun <T> LazyListScope.itemsWithAd(
    items: List<T>,
    adItem: @Composable LazyItemScope.() -> Unit,
    adPosition: Int = 0,
    itemContent: @Composable LazyItemScope.(T) -> Unit
) {
    val before = items.subList(0, adPosition)
    val after = items.subList(adPosition, items.size)
    items(before) { itemContent(it) }
    item("ad") { adItem() }
    items(after) { itemContent(it) }
}
```

This should allow you to draw any content you wish at any arbitrary point within a lazy row or column. You should be able to apply something similar for a lazy grid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your certain position UI Items -->

```
                        @Composable
                        fun CustomLazyColumn(
                            viewModel: MyViewModel,
                            modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
                        ) {
                            LazyColumn(modifier = modifier) {
                                items(viewModel.standardItems) { item ->
                                    // Render your standard items here
                                    // You can use any Composable to display the item
                                    StandardItem(item)
                                }

                                item {
                                    // Render your custom item
                                    CustomItem()
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Composable
                        fun StandardItem(item: String) {
                            // Your standard item Composable
                        }

                        @Composable
                        fun CustomItem() {
                            // Your custom item Composable
                        }

                        @Composable
                        fun CustomLazyColumnScreen(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
                            CustomLazyColumn(
                                viewModel = viewModel,
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                            )
                        }

                        @Composable
                        @Preview
                        fun CustomLazyColumnPreview() {
                            val standardItems = remember { List(50) { "Item $it" } }
                            val viewModel = remember { MyViewModel(standardItems) }
                            CustomLazyColumnScreen(viewModel)
                        }

                        class MyViewModel(standardItems: List<String>) : ViewModel() {
                            var standardItems by mutableStateOf(standardItems)
                            
                            // Add custom items to the list
                            fun addCustomItem() {
                                standardItems = standardItems.toMutableList().apply {
                                    add("Custom Item ${Random.nextInt(100)}")
                                }
                            }
                        }
```