# How to check the % visibility of a Composable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a `Composable` that is on a `LazyColumn` but I'm trying to do the check of visibility out of the `LazyListState` I used to use this

```
fun LazyListState.visibleItems(itemVisiblePercentThreshold: Float) =
    layoutInfo
        .visibleItemsInfo
        .filter {
            visibilityPercent(it) >= itemVisiblePercentThreshold
        }

private fun LazyListState.visibilityPercent(info: LazyListItemInfo): Float {
    val cutTop = maxOf(0, layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset - info.offset)
    val cutBottom = maxOf(0, info.offset + info.size - layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset)

    return maxOf(0f, 100f - (cutTop + cutBottom) * 100f / info.size)
}
```

But now I want it inside the `Composable` since I do not have access to the list, others features use my `Composables` and it could be inside a `LazyList`, `Surface`, whatever, so I'm using `onGloballyPositioned`to determine if it's visible or not, but I'd like to know if it's at least 30% visible. Any idea?

### Explanation

I have a `@Composable` that I want to provide to other features of my app, so for example :

Feature1 have a `LazyColumn` that prints its items, but then they want to add my `@Composable` to the top of the list, so I want to know when my `@Composable` is visible (at least 30%) on this case if it's at the top normally it should be always 100% when load the list but for example in Feature2 they want to add my `@Composable` at the middle of their list, so I should know when it start to be visible that's why I need the threshold to send some events.

It wont be always a `LazyColumn` that's why I don't know if I want to be attached to a `LazyListState` but if needed I could receive a `LazyListState` on my `@Composable`.

Comment: Make a `State` variable and use it to save the output from your `visibleItemsInfo`. Then you can use it anywhere you want.

Comment: @Jorn may you put an example of doing it please? Remember, I don't have access to where it is located, I don't know if it's inside a LazyColumn, LazyRow, nothing (maybe internally I could know) but I just provide my composable to other features

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wish to use this with any Compoasble you can use `Modifier.onGloballyPositioned{}`

[image]

```
fun Modifier.isVisible(
    parentCoordinates: LayoutCoordinates?,
    threshold: Int,
    onVisibilityChange: (Boolean) -> Unit
) = composed {

    val view = LocalView.current

    Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { layoutCoordinates: LayoutCoordinates ->

        if (parentCoordinates == null) return@onGloballyPositioned

        val layoutHeight = layoutCoordinates.size.height
        val thresholdHeight = layoutHeight * threshold / 100
        val layoutTop = layoutCoordinates.positionInRoot().y

        val parentTop = parentCoordinates.positionInParent().y

        val parentHeight = parentCoordinates.size.height
        val parentBottom = (parentTop + parentHeight).coerceAtMost(view.height.toFloat())
        println(
            "layoutTop: $layoutTop, " +
                    " parentTop: $parentTop, " +
                    " parentBottom: $parentBottom, " +
                    "parentHeight: $parentHeight, " +
                    "SECTION: ${parentBottom - layoutTop}"
        )

        if (
            parentBottom - layoutTop > thresholdHeight &&
            (layoutTop - parentTop > thresholdHeight - layoutHeight)
        ) {
            onVisibilityChange(true)
        } else {
            onVisibilityChange(false)

        }
    }
}
```

I posted a little bit complex example to show you can get position no matter where parent is positioned in its parent.

You can use it with LazyColumn or Column with vertical scroll.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ScrollTest() {

    var isVisible by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    var coordinates by remember {
        mutableStateOf<LayoutCoordinates?>(null)
    }

    val context = LocalContext.current

    var visibleTime by remember {
        mutableLongStateOf(0L)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(isVisible) {

        if (isVisible) {
            visibleTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            Toast.makeText(context, " Item 30% threshold is passed $isVisible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        } else if (visibleTime != 0L) {
            val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val totalTime = currentTime - visibleTime
            Toast.makeText(context, " Item was visible for $totalTime ms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }
    }


    Column {

        Box(modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp))

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .onPlaced { layoutCoordinates: LayoutCoordinates ->
                    coordinates = layoutCoordinates
                }
                .weight(1f)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .border(2.dp, Color.Black)
        ) {
            items(60) { index: Int ->
                if (index == 15) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(300.dp)
                            .border(6.dp, if (isVisible) Color.Green else Color.Red)
                            .isVisible(parentCoordinates = coordinates, threshold = 30) {
                                isVisible = it
                            }
                    ) {
                        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(3f).background(Color.Yellow))
                        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(4f).background(Color.Cyan))
                        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(3f).background(Color.Magenta))
                    }
                } else {
                    Text(
                        text = "Row $index",
                        fontSize = 24.sp,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }


//        Column(
//            modifier = Modifier
//                .onPlaced { layoutCoordinates: LayoutCoordinates ->
//                    coordinates = layoutCoordinates
//                }
//                .weight(1f)
//                .fillMaxSize()
//                .border(2.dp, Color.Black)
//                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
//        ) {
//            repeat(60) { index ->
//                if (index == 15) {
//                    Column(
//                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(300.dp)
//                            .border(6.dp, if (isVisible) Color.Green else Color.Red)
//                            .isVisible(parentCoordinates = coordinates, threshold = 30) {
//                                isVisible = it
//                            }
//                    ) {
//                        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(3f).background(Color.Yellow))
//                        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(4f).background(Color.Cyan))
//                        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(3f).background(Color.Magenta))
//                    }
//                } else {
//                    Text(
//                        text = "Row $index",
//                        fontSize = 24.sp,
//                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp)
//                    )
//                }
//            }
//        }
        Box(modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp))

    }
}
```

## Edit

If you have don't want to pass parent LayoutCoordinates you can update this modifier as

```
fun Modifier.isVisible(
    threshold: Int,
    onVisibilityChange: (Boolean) -> Unit
) = composed {
    
    Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { layoutCoordinates: LayoutCoordinates ->
        val layoutHeight = layoutCoordinates.size.height
        val thresholdHeight = layoutHeight * threshold / 100
        val layoutTop = layoutCoordinates.positionInRoot().y
        val layoutBottom = layoutTop + layoutHeight

        // This should be parentLayoutCoordinates not parentCoordinates
        val parent =
            layoutCoordinates.parentLayoutCoordinates

        parent?.boundsInRoot()?.let { rect: Rect ->
            val parentTop = rect.top
            val parentBottom = rect.bottom
            
            if (
                parentBottom - layoutTop > thresholdHeight &&
                (parentTop < layoutBottom - thresholdHeight)
            ) {
                onVisibilityChange(true)
            } else {
                onVisibilityChange(false)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use this for multiple Composables create a custom one as

```
@Composable
private fun MyCustomBox(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    threshold: Int = 30,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    var isVisible by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    val context = LocalContext.current

    var visibleTime by remember {
        mutableLongStateOf(0L)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(isVisible) {

        if (isVisible) {
            visibleTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            Toast.makeText(context, " Item 30% threshold is passed $isVisible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        } else if (visibleTime != 0L) {
            val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val totalTime = currentTime - visibleTime
            Toast.makeText(context, " Item was visible for $totalTime ms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .border(6.dp, if (isVisible) Color.Green else Color.Red)
            .isVisible(threshold = threshold) {
                isVisible = it
            }
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

And you can use it as

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ScrollTest2() {


    Column {

        TopAppBar {
            Text("TopAppbar")
        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f)
                .border(2.dp, Color.Black)
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {
            repeat(60) { index ->
                if (index == 15 || index == 22 || index == 35) {
                    MyCustomBox(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(300.dp)
                    ) {
                        Column {
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(3f)
                                    .background(Color.Yellow)
                            )
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(4f).background(Color.Cyan)
                            )
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(3f)
                                    .background(Color.Magenta)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Text(
                        text = "Row $index",
                        fontSize = 24.sp,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        Box(modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp))

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Thracian I'll take a look, with this example can I include my composable in any list of my app and get notified when 30% is shown? and for instance if it's visible for n seconds?

Comment: Sure, inside LaunchedEffect add a time when it's true and after delay trigger an event

Comment: If you check the demo you will see that it's a Modifier that i assigned to Composable in Column with vertical scroll(comment out to try out) and LazyColumn

Comment: Timer is very simple as you do any timer inside LaunchedEffect it's also easy to implement

Comment: @StuartDTO updated answer with time to display how long  at least 30%  of item was on screen

Comment: amazing help really I appreciate it a lot, but I'm seeing lot of code in the list, and I'm the owner of my composable, so I shouldn't add code to the list, is it possible to have it all inside the Composable? I mean, the context is, I have a Composable that I want to share among the app and it will be (90% sure) they'll use it inside a list, but the composable itself should be smart enough to know everything, is it possible sir?

Comment: You are seeing lots of code because i posted to show that you can use it in complex situations. All you need to do use Modifier.isVisible() but you need to pass LayoutCoordinates of parent. `Modifier.isVisible(parentCoordinates = coordinates, threshold = 30) {isVisible = it}` is the only code you need to use to detect whether your composable is visible at least with predefined percentage.

Comment: If you want you can move LaunchedEffect inside Modifier itself either

Comment: Parent Coordinates is the one you get from Column or LazyList to determine its size, and position on screen if there are other Composables. As you can see in my sample i added Boxes before and after them to make sure that this Modifier should work in many cases not only when you have one scrollable Column or LazyList. If you have one scrollable fullscreen item you can change modifier to not get parents LayoutCoordinates

Comment: And you don't add code to List, every Composable should have Modifier parameter, you are getting Layoutcoordinates from it, nothing to do with List or scrollable Column itself

Comment: Could you post an example of for instance MyComposable it's the thing I want to provide, and a LazyColumn from other features that have Item1 Item2 and want to add MyComposable at three position for instance so I can have a try?

Comment: @StuartDTO if you don't want to pass LayoutCoordinates from parent and scrollable Column or LazyColumn is fullscreen you can use this one.

Comment: no, rarelly would be full screen, if will be LazyColumn, LazyRow, etc... so what would be the efficient approach in your humble opinion? Trying to not modify lot of code of their features?

Comment: BTW just tested your solution and looks is working fine, the thing is that I'd like to the visibility things occur inside the Composable, not in the list of the other feature

Comment: Because other solution I was thinking of is to create a custom LazyRow/LazyColumn that depending on the parameter I send to it it ads the custom composable Top/Bot/Combined, but then I faced problems with sections, sticky headers, index, etc... could be a better solution do this?

Comment: @StuartDTO here you go. Full sample with Modifier that takes no other params and can be used with multiple items.

Comment: Cool, I'll test in some hours, thanks for your effort sir!

Comment: it worked, thank you so much for your help, I'm going to open another question to avoid this get bigger about the second option, create a `LazyColumn` custom to dettermine the composables and put them inside. I'll link in some minutes

Comment: Is this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77213599/create-custom-lazycolumn-lazylist-to-add-custom-items-in-between, you can re-use the custom modifier + custom view if you want to answer... Thank you

Comment: Great that it works. This question helped me a lot to learn about ModifieronGloaballyPositioned  `parentCoordinates` and `parentLayoutCoordinates`, that's why i upvoted it. You can use `layoutCoordinates.parentLayoutCoordinates` instead of `layoutCoordinates.parentCoordinates?.parentLayoutCoordinates` they both give the same coordinates.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77213599/create-custom-lazycolumn-lazylist-to-add-custom-items-in-between I'm not able to understand relationship between question and this answer? What's exactly the expected result?

Comment: Well, it's related because this question is if I don't get the LazyColumn result, and I'll provide just the `Composable` to the feature list, but in case I could create like `OffersLazyColumn` and the lazycolumn itself do the work of adding the offers depending on the configuration would be better. But there are a lot of corner cases there and wanted to know if there's another solution to do that. It's just my feature let's say is Offers and then the rest of my app want to include Offers on their list. (it's like a library)

Comment: just updated the question with more information, with an image with desired behaviour etc, let me know if you need further information to help me out. Thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `snapshotFlow` to easily monitor the visible items:

```kotlin
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val visibleItems by remember {
        snapshotFlow {
            val layoutInfo = listState.layoutInfo
            layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.map {
                val cutTop = (layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset - it.offset).coerceAtLeast(0)
                val cutBottom = (it.offset + it.size - layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset).coerceAtLeast(0)
                val visiblePart = (it.size.toFloat() - cutTop - cutBottom) / it.size
                it to visiblePart
            }
        }
    }.collectAsState(emptyList())
    LazyColumn(state = listState) {
        items((1..9).toList(), {it}) { key ->
            Box(Modifier.height(100.dp * key).border(2.dp, Color.Black)) {
                val measurement = visibleItems.firstOrNull { it.first.key == key }?.second ?: 0f
                Text("Item $key: Visible part $measurement")
                Text("Item $key: Visible part $measurement", Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter))
            }
        }
    }
```

This will recalculate how much every item is visible, whenever the scroll state changes, then show you the visible part in the UI.

Comment: I don't have any listState, I want to check if is visible the composable and if is visible of a treshhold I don't know if this composable is inside a list or not, maybe I can add as a parameter of my composable the listState? But if not how can I do it without it?

Comment: This whole thing hinges on a scrollable view. It makes no sense without one. So you should always have some kind of lazy list state.

Comment: Where to use this visibileItems? Because I just want to check if is visible my composable I don't care about rest

Comment: @StuartDTO See updated answer. The `visibleItems` will only contain actually *visible* items. Be sure to provide an explicit key function to the `items` call, or getting the right item from the list won't work.

Comment: *"So you should always have some kind of lazy list state."* That's not really true; you can have a scrollable Column that's not a lazy list, for example.

Comment: @Jorn the thing is that I don't have a lazy list state, couldn't be done in the `onGloballyPositioned`modifier method? Because it's a `@Composable` that I provide to other features, let me update the question

Comment: @RyanM Edited my question

Comment: So you *do* have a `LazyColumn`, but don't want to use `LazyListState`? Or there are other cases where it's not a `LazyColumn`? If it's the latter, then what component *are* you using?

Comment: Thing is I provide a Composable but I'm not 100% sure they'll use it on a LazyColumn, so that's why I'm asking the two options one if they can provide to me the LazyListState for me is ok, but if not, how can I check if my composable is 30% visible on the screen?

Comment: Still makes no sense. How can your component be partially visible if it's not inside a scrollable component?

Comment: Yes, maybe you are right, and it should always have a lazyListState, so could you please post an answer sample one to accept LazyListState and just know if my composable it's visible at least 30%? because their list could have LazyColumns that have LazyColumn { PersonItem() AnimalItem() MyComposable() ... } so I want to know only when "MyComposable()" is visible, is that possible?

Comment: That's exactly what the current answer does. You will need the key for your composable and filter on `visiblePart > 0.3f`.

Answer (score 0):

[Visibility Tracker](https://github.com/hevinxx/visibility-tracker) detects the visibililty ratio changed even if you have nested lazy columns and rows.

```
VisibilityTracker(
    threshold = 0.3f,
    onVisibilityChanged = { isVisible ->
        if (isVisible) yourLogic()
    },
    treatOnStopAsInvisible = true
) {
    // Your composable content here
}
```